# Ошибка "aab подписан с помощью неправильного ключа" при загрузке приложения в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-console

Когда первый раз пытался загрузить приложение в Google Play в формате aab, то появилась такая ошибка:

> Набор Android App Bundle подписан с помощью неправильного ключа. Выберите правильный ключ и повторите попытку. Набор App Bundle должен быть подписан сертификатом с цифровым отпечатком
> SHA1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> . Однако для загруженного набора App Bundle используется сертификат с цифровым отпечатком
> SHA1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,

У меня в Android Studio и в Google Play разные сертификаты, уже раз 10 перегенирировался aab-файл, и также разные сертификаты подписание (SHA-1), вроде нужно использовать

```
$ keytool -export -rfc  -keystore your-upload-keystore.jks  -alias upload-alias -file output_upload_certificate.pem,
```

или нет, не знаю, а если так, то где взять `output_upload_certificate.pem`?

Comment: Как и чем вы подписываете приложение когда его собираете?

Comment: Через build-> Generate Signed Bundle/APK, потом выбираю Android App Bundle. потом создаю через Create new.. и заполняю поля key store path, password и alias и тд. А потом еще в ручную подписывал через app-> open module settings, там добавлял release.

Comment: Также с каждой новой генерацией, был новый сертификат SHA-1, который хранился keystore.jks файле.

Comment: Вам не надо каждый раз создавать новый ключ. Наоборот, надо всегда самый первый использовать, сохранив его и пароли с алиасом в надёжном месте. Если изначальный ключ не сохранился - ищите в консоли разработчика опцию замены загрузочного ключа на ваш новый ключ.

Comment: А теперь начинаю понимать, что он один раз в google play создался, но чтобы обновить его, нужно запросить доступ через службу поддержки. Но же можно как-то сделать через keytool -export -rfc -keystore your-upload-keystore.jks -alias upload-alias -file output_upload_certificate.pem, вот только не совсем понимаю где взять output_upload_certificate.pem - это вроде же внешний, а из google play можно скачать сертификат в формате upload.der,  а здесь .pem.

Answer (score 0):

1. чуть выше поля, в котором размещена кнопка для загрузки aab есть почти незаметная синяя ссылка "изменить ключ подписи приложения". Её нужно нажать (обновится ключ).

---

! если эту версию aab уже загружал, и он матерится (версия и пакет уже загружались),
значит в BuildGradle(ModuleApp) нужно поменять версию приложения и версию кода
versionCode 1   (увеличить на 1)
versionName "1.1"  (поменять на что угодно, например 1.2)

---

2. Сгенерировать новый aab

---

3. Затем загружать aab в консоль.

---

подробнее здесь:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

Comment: versionName менять не обязательно, достаточно только увеличить versionCode и можно снова заливать .aab или .apk